# MacOS_Numbers+ python script

Tags: python, macos, numbers

I'm trying to run a basic code using the library numbers-parser 3.9.5. Here I'm trying to get values from cells A1 and B2 like in example of description of this library:
`https://pypi.org/project/numbers-parser/`

```
from numbers_parser import Document
doc = Document("demo.numbers")
sheets = doc.sheets
tables = sheets[0].tables
data = tables["Table 1"].rows()
print("Cell A1 contains", data[0][0])
print("Cell B2 contains", data[1][1])
```

But instead of getting values, I'm getting this response:

```
Cell A1 contains <numbers_parser.cell.EmptyCell object at 0x10d38eb00>
Cell B2 contains <numbers_parser.cell.EmptyCell object at 0x10d38ec50>
```

The actual values of A1 is null(nothing there), B1 is 1. What is it and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the documentation it notes that "All cell types have a property value which returns the contents of the cell in as a native Python datatype."

```
print("Cell A1 contains", data[0][0].value)
print("Cell B2 contains", data[1][1].value)
```

should produce

```
Cell A1 contains 1.0
Cell B2 contains 4.0
```

if A1 and B2 were to contain the values 1 and 4, respectively.